# Prove that given primes in ascending order where $p_1<p_2<,\ldots$, the following is true: $p_{n+1} \leq p_1p_2...p_n + 1 \quad \forall n \in \Bbb N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have absolutely no idea where to start, since I hardly ever have to use inequalities when it comes to working with primes. If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it.
An example that shows what the inequality is trying to prove is: $p_1=2, \, p_2=3, \, p_3=5 \implies p_3 = 5 \leq p_1p_2+1 = 2.3+1$

Edit: It was very confusing and badly worded so I fixed it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euclid’s proof of infinitely many primes?

Comment: Hi, to me it does not seem clear what the actual inequality you want to show is.

Comment: @Watercrystal: the OP is trying to show $$p_{n+1}\leq p_1\cdots p_n+1$$ where $p_n$ represents the $n^{th}$ prime.

Comment: Ah, I read $p_n$ rather than $p_{n+1}$, my bad.

Comment: @Watercrystal Yes, that's it

Answer (score 2):

$p_1p_2\dots p_n+1$ cannot be divisible by $p_1, p_2, ..., $ or $p_n$,

because it leaves remainder $1$ when divided by any of those primes.

Therefore, $p_1p_2\dots p_n+1$ is prime or divisible by a prime greater than $p_n$.

In any case, there is another prime besides $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ that is at most $p_1p_2\dots p_n+1$.

Therefore, $p_{n+1}\le p_1p_2\dots p_n+1$.

---

This is how [Euclid proved there are infinitely many primes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidsTheorems.html).

$p_1p_2\dots p_n$ is called the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial).

Comment: Very clear explanation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This result also follows from Bertrand's postulate (now proved) which states that in the interval between any integer $k$ and $2k$ there is at least one prime. This also holds when $k$ is a prime, for example $p_n<p_{n+1}<2p_n$.

So if $p_1p_2\dots p_{n-1}\ge 2$ then $p_n<p_{n+1}<2p_n\le p_1p_2\dots p_{n-1}p_n<p_1p_2\dots p_{n-1}p_n+1$.

Comment: Interesting. Did not know about that. Thank you!